# Boxing to type in ironpython

Tags: c#, ironpython, mvvm-light, boxing

Iv'e got a Messenger (MVVM Light Toolkit) registered to listen for ViewModelBase
In Iron Python I'd like to send a ViewModel that I got, and box it as a ViewModelBase so that the messenger receives it. 
So what is the equivalent to:

```
var viewmodel = new MyViewModel();
Messenger.Default.Send((ViewModelBase)viewmodel);
```

in iron python, or is there another work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at MVVM Light, it appears that `Messenger.Send` is generic. If that's the case (and I'm looking at the right method), then IronPython requires you to explicitly set the type parameters like so:

```
viewmodel = MyViewModel()
Messenger.Default.Send[ViewModelBase](viewmodel)
```